# Missing unpackedMatrix_diag_get

Tags: dependencies

I'm trying to use the function clusterperm.lmer() from the *permutes* package on a Mac. After reinstalling R however, I always get the following error.

Error in diag(from, names = FALSE) :
object 'unpackedMatrix_diag_get' not found

I first thought this had to do with some unresolved dependencies between packages, but after updating all the packages, and even after uninstalling R and all the contents of its Framework folder, the error still occurs...

Has anyone else run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that problem today. After all, it was a compatibility issue with another package. I restarted R, removed the problematic package from my script, and everything is back to normal again.